# android cts: Why does package run fail but individual tests pass?

Tags: android, cts

I'm hitting failures when running

```
  cts-tf > run cts --package android.holo
```

but when I run the failed tests individually, like

```
cts-tf > run cts --class android.holo.cts.HoloTest --method testHoloWallpaperNoTitleBar
```

they pass.

Without knowing the internals, I'd expect that something that failed a package test would fail an individual test.  If there was a dependency on a previous test, then if anything failed it would be the individual test.

Is this a **cts** timing issue, something expected with holo, or something else?  If you understand it, please enlighten me, I'm new to **cts**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe that test case is affected by another test case in same class or package
But in case it's pass when re-run, you could just it is pass

Answer (score 2):

Holo test cases are usually for screen resolution of the Device under Test.
You can ask Google for wave-off on these tests if you are running the tests on Mobile.

As per the previous answer, there could be a chance that previous set of test cases are causing some issues leading to failures of Holo tests (but I doubt this)